# Post release trigger on VSTS, to run end to end test suite

Tags: azure-devops

Is there an option to trigger a test-suite based on `javascript` somehow?

I do run unit-tests as part of our build process, but when I have made a release I would like to run some end to end tests. And I am not sure where on `VSTS` I would trigger something like that.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you run unit-tests in build, triggered by some scripts?

Comment: triggered. But this end to end suite is based on Javascript and NPM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add tasks for E2E tests in the end of your release definition, and conditional runs E2E tests based on your javascript (upload the file as build artifacts if necessary) and [custom conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/conditions).

Comment: I don't want javascript to trigger anything. I want something on VSTS to trigger a javascript file. Thanks

Comment: So you add related tasks (such as npm install, gulp etc) in the end of your release definition. After all the tasks are deployed successful, then the new added tasks will execute.

Comment: Believe I am catching on now. Thanks!